# UDF adding two series spark pandas udf

Tags: apache-spark, scipy, user-defined-functions

My problem is trying to link scipy api with pyspark using UDF

```
columns = ['N','P']
data = [(1,3),
    (3,3),
    (5,3)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)


+---+---+
|N  |P  |
+---+---+
|1  |3  |
|3  |3  |
|5  |3  |
+---+---+

@pandas_udf("col1 int, col2 int")
def func(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    import scipy 
    
    s3 = s1 + s2*scipy.pi
    return s3
```

The desired output after using this function is a new column added with the transformation thanks in advance

```
df2 = df.withColumn('transformed',func("N", "P"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> @pandas_udf(FloatType())
... def p_udf(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
...   return s1 + (s2 * 3.14)
... 
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1,3), (3,3), (5,3)], schema=['N','P'])
>>> df.withColumn('transformed', p_udf("N", "P")).show()
+---+---+-----------+
|  N|  P|transformed|
+---+---+-----------+
|  1|  3|      10.42|
|  3|  3|      12.42|
|  5|  3|      14.42|
+---+---+-----------+

>>>
```

Comment: I have a similar function but  for some reason I am getting 'TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>' thanks a lot

Comment: @FalconX, you might be confusing between pandas and spark udf, OR trying to do some operation on [`pd.Series`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) that's not provided in it. In any case, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter for `@pandas_udf` is the return type of the function, not the type of the input parameters.

Changing the code to

```python
from pyspark.sql import types as T

@F.pandas_udf(T.FloatType())
def func(s1: pd.Series, s2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  [...]
```

should work.

Comment: I have a similar function but  for some reason I am getting 'TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>' thanks a lot